# Deploy JWT as remote service or common library

Tags: java, jwt, single-sign-on

I have multiple applications installed at our organization. which of the following is the best practice to deploy JWT/JWS/JWE component to be consumed by applications to single sign on with third party applications.

1. Deploy it as a remote API/component on separate host
2. Create a java library for JWT/JWS/JWE and install it in nexus repository. And let my consumer applications include it as a maven pom dependency in thier respective projects.

What will drive above two decision?

Thanks,

Comment: It is better to keep JWT tokens away from the client-side as hackers can easily decode it and get useful pieces of information. Keeping that in mind I have given you the suggestion. better be secure than late. https://medium.com/swlh/hacking-json-web-tokens-jwts-9122efe91e4a